# % of mobile/android devices with specifc features

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I'm looking for information about % of mobile devices with specifc features.

When you start a project in Android Studio and select the Minimum SDK, it provide information about the amount of compatible devices that are active on the Google Play Store

[image]

Is there any way to get information like?

- % of android devices with GPS
- % of android devices with NFC
- % of android devices with frontal cam

I hope that Google Play Developer Console  give something like that, but i hav'nt this access yet

This kind of information would be very useful while you design a app

Comment: If you look up android version history it logs software changes. As for percentage of android devices with cameras/GPS, that depends on the manufacturers

Comment: I would like to know if there is public for an app that needs NFC or GPS. Or if there are only a limited number of people with...

Comment: I don't know of any good source of that data.  Google does not provide it.  GPS should be nearly universal, but NFC is much less so, especially on older devices.